# how to select multiple items in select element using ASP.NET without pressing CTRL key?

Tags: asp.net-core, multiple-select

I have this Code in order to choose multiple stores but it can only be done using CTRL key.

```
<select asp-for="Store" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Store"></select>
```

I tried the multiple attribute but it didn't work as well.
I can't also use JS on the options here because they aren't labeled with the option element.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by they aren't labeled with the option element.
You can add a class to each option and assign this to the mousedown event. Even if you have to add that class after the page has loaded.

```
$('.togglable-option').mousedown(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop('selected', !$(this).prop('selected'));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I meant that I don't have any options at all because the `asp-items="ViewBag.Store"` is presenting all of the options automatically so I don't have it built-in on HTML

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can use `bootstrap-multiselect.js` and `bootstrap-multiselect.css` to meet your demand:

```
<select asp-for="Store" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Store" multiple> 
</select>
@section Scripts
{   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.12/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" integrity="sha512-S1l1mfpQS+XBPSgS8cCqElwRx24IcAYrwxLJg6WaFkG9J8bfNuilkoqkGny/rz7jS7Bo03qnzeBtE9LElt/fDg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.12/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js" integrity="sha512-aWn1p8Melh1IyDRnXpJBvt1vZrGoObLXR5p9WaYfJY0bt0O8xGVCuEd2xlXIdRJjpwTybY07RlVs4N0ePGXUZQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Store").multiselect();

        })
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Showed me the menu with "None Selected" and I could not choose anything

Comment: Hi @ShimonCohen, please share your enough code to let me reproduce the issue. The code above works for me.